# How can I eliminate/remove a duplication of an object array element which is duplicated a ton of time in the array. (Return same array type)

Tags: java, arrays, object, element

I tried this for loop but when for duplicated element in the array the inner loop breaks and if more than 10 repeated element are place in the array then the outer-loop brakes.

I need to return an array of same object type since I need to use the methods to pick some values from it.

```
public Mode insT(Guide[] guide){
  Guide[] guideVo = checkGuideDuplication(guide);
}

public Guide[] checkGuideDuplication (Guide[] guide){
  for(int i = 0; i<guide.length-1; i++){
    for(int j = i+1; i<guide.length; i++){
     if(guide[i].getGuide().trim().equals(guide[j].getGuide().trim())){
      guide = (Guide[]) ArrayUtils.remove(guide); 
   }
  }
 }
 return guide;
}
```

Comment: Shove it in a `Set` then back into an array.

Comment: Why `ArrayUtils.remove` accepts only the array `guide`?  Shouldn't you pass at least the index of the element to be removed `ArrayUtils.remove(guide, j)`?

Comment: Also, there seems to be a typo in the inner loop: `j` is never incremented and compared to `guide.length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset the inner index once you remove an element so it gets checked (and bounds-checked) again:

```
guide = (Guide[]) ArrayUtils.remove(guide);
j--;
```

You can avoid the inner loop entirely if you use a map to weed out duplicates:

```
public Guide[] checkGuideDuplication (Guide[] guide){
  Map<String, Guide> uniques = new HashMap<>();
  for(Guide g : guide){
    uniques.putIfAbsent(g.getGuide().trim(), g);
  }
  return uniques.values().toArray(new Guide[0]);
}
```

Comment: Both solutions work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The most performing O(N) solution would be to use `Map` as shown in [shmosel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70194775/13279831).

But if using `Map` is not an option due to some constraints/limitations (e.g. only arrays are allowed), another solution would be to set removed elements to `null` and count the number of deletions, then shift `null`s to the end of the array and return a truncated array:

```java
public Guide[] checkGuideDuplication (Guide ... guide) {
    int deleted = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < guide.length-1; i++) {
        if (null == guide[i]) {
            continue;
        }
        String currGuide = guide[i].getGuide().trim();

        for(int j = i + 1; j < guide.length; j++) {
            if (null == guide[j]) {
                continue;
            }
            if (currGuide.equals(guide[j].getGuide().trim())) {
                guide[j] = null;
                deleted++;
            }
        }
    }
    // shift remaining elements
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < guide.length; i++) {
        if (guide[i] != null) {
            guide[j++] = guide[i];
        }
    }
    return Arrays.copyOf(guide, guide.length - deleted);
}
```

Comment: Both solutions work fine.